# Dynamically reference propertyName+1 in loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, optimization

Trying to clean up some code and having issues doing so. I have a 1-5 ranking that appears in a uitableviewcell. The cell has 5 imageviews that point to a star image. There is a starYellow.png and starGrey.png. If the ranking is 3/5, the cell should set star1, star2, star3 to starYellow.png and star4, star5 to starGrey.png.

I am having issues referencing the property star%i where i is the iteration of the loop 1-5. I can't work out how to do something like [cell setValue:starYellow forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"star%i.image", i]];

Here is the code I want to optimize..

```
if (book.ratingOnline) {
[cell.ratingView.layer setOpacity:1.0f];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {            
        if (i == 1) {
            if (book.ratingOnline >= i) { [cell.star1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starYellow.png"]]; }
            else { [cell.star1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starGrey.png"]]; }
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            if (book.ratingOnline >= i) { [cell.star2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starYellow.png"]]; }
            else { [cell.star2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starGrey.png"]]; }
        }
        else if (i == 3) {
            if (book.ratingOnline >= i) { [cell.star3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starYellow.png"]]; }
            else { [cell.star3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starGrey.png"]]; }
        }
        else if (i == 4) {
            if (book.ratingOnline >= i) { [cell.star4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starYellow.png"]]; }
            else { [cell.star4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starGrey.png"]]; }
        }
        else if (i == 5) {
            if (book.ratingOnline >= i) { [cell.star5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starYellow.png"]]; }
            else { [cell.star5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starGrey.png"]]; }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the stars in an NSArray,

in Cell.h

```
NSArray *stars;
```

Now to reference any start you could do

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {            
     UIImageView *star = [cell.stars objectAtIndex:i];
     //set the image to the star
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I didn't know you could reference properties like that. Changed objectAtIndex:i to i-1 to deal with the correct bounds for the looping and it does the trick.